# Block with multiple parameters as argument in swift/objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to pass a Swift function (with multiple parameters, defined as a closure) to an Objective-C function. Technically, the function is defined in Objective-C++, but I'm encountering an issue at the header level, so it should be equivalent for this question.

In the Objective-C header, I have this defined as:

```
@interface MyObjCClass : NSObject
typedef void (^MyCallback)(NSMutableData*, int);

- (void) functionThatTakesACallback: (MyCallback) callback;
```

In swift, I'm trying to use it in this way:

```
self.objcclass!.functionThatTakesACallback()
{
    (values: NSMutableData, length: Int32) -> Void in
        // Do something with this data.
}
```

The error I get is:

> Cannot convert value of type `'(NSMutableData, Int32) -> Void'` to expected argument type `'MyCallback!'`

If I unwrap that a bit, by putting the block directly into the Objective-C function definition (sans typedef):

```
- (void) functionThatTakesACallback: (void (^)(NSMutableData*, int)) callback;
```

it gives me the vaguely more helpful:

> Cannot convert value of type `'(NSMutableData, Int32) -> Void'` to expected argument type `'((NSMutableData!, Int32) -> Void)!'`

So, essentially, is there any way to unwrap this closure to fit the expected type? Or redefine the Objective-C type?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to add nullability attributes to your callback parameter and to the callback argument for your function. There are two ways you could do it.

Add the nullability annotations to each place that needs it.

```
@interface MyObjCClass : NSObject
typedef void (^MyCallback)(nonnull NSMutableData*, int);

- (void) functionThatTakesACallback: (nonnull MyCallback) callback;
```

Set the whole file to assume nonnull

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyObjCClass : NSObject
typedef void (^MyCallback)(NSMutableData*, int);

- (void) functionThatTakesACallback: (MyCallback) callback;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just managed to fix this, but because the solution is simple but rather non-intuitive given the error message, here is the solution:

The function call from Swift must actually be:

```
self.objcclass!.functionThatTakesACallback()
{
    (values: NSMutableData!, length: Int32!) -> Void in
        // Do something with this data.
}
```

Comment: You should try to avoid using forced unwrapping (`!`) because usually an optional is there for a good reason. Instead take in the optional with `?` and test to see if it contains a value. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35588818/887210) on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For the parameter `values` Objective-C is expecting a pointer to an object and that pointer could be nil. In Swift that translates to an `optional` value. An `optional` is followed by a `?` and should be unwrapped  - checked for nil and if there's an object there then return it.

Try:

```
self.objcclass!.functionThatTakesACallback() {
  (values: NSMutableData?, length: Int32) -> Void in
    if let values = values { // first values is a local, second values is unwrapped into it
      // Do something with this data.
    }
  }
```